# how to design step groove pcb in altium designer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

I need to design a multilayer pcb in altium designer that has cutout just in one layer. I was seeking that and I found out that in china it is called 阶梯槽. I translated to English but I didn't find any solution about step groove or step slot. I will appreciate it if anyone can help me out.

Comment: What do you mean "cut out in one layer" is that an area with no copper? In which case there is a "keep out" tool (I think in the tools or place menu) which does this.

Comment: I read it as meaning reduced thickness over part of the area due to a cutout in part of the layup. Hopefully, an outer part of the layup.  The most obvious question would be: what for?

Comment: Just so we are on the same page: like this one: http://www.lianhuixin.com/en/58g-sensing-plate.html 
?

Comment: exactly what you are looking for is in my mind. But I can't find how to design it in altium disigner. @ocrdu

Comment: It is used for High frequency application actually. @BrianDrummond

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there's a cutout made in a specified layer before lamination. Assuming it is something like [this](http://www.zlpcb.com/wap/NewsShow.asp?NewsId=720):

[image: this]

I think you would create an outline for the stackup layer that needs the cutout milled/routed out of it, as well as an overall board outline.

So add mechanical layer and draw the cutouts and add text to explain what it means.

But definitely talk to the vendor to make sure that everything is clear, otherwise you might get some expensive scrap.  Keep the radius on the inside holes reasonable or it will either be very expensive or they might even ignore it and use a big diameter cutter.

It's possible you could get something that renders in 3D helpfully by using the rigid-flex features in Altium, not sure I would bother though.

Answer (score 0):

ev. Embedded components can solve this:
[Altium Help Embedded Components](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/embedded-components-ad?version=18.1)